# How do I attach large bookmarklet code to href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bookmarklet

I have a bookmarklet that's about 100 lines long. Normally I'd attach the bookmarklet code to an anchor tag like so:

```
            <a href=javascript:function(){ * TEH CODEZ *} >
```

This is of course so someone can click and drag the link to their bookmarks bar for simple setup of the bookmarklet.

The problem is I don't know how to do the same thing with a long bookmarklet. Right now I'm including the code directly into a DIV tag then using JS to attach the contents of the div to the href attribute of the anchor tag directly:

```
            <div id="bookmarklet_code" class="hide">
                <?php include('bookmarklet.js'); ?>
            </div>
            <script>
                $('#bookmarklet_anchor').attr('href',$('#bookmarklet_code').html());
            </script>
```

Sadly this doesn't work so I must still be doing something wrong. I can drag it to my bookmarks bar ok, but when I review the code, it has extra characters and doesn't work. Clearly I'm missing some fundamental information about how this is supposed to work.

Comment: Need to be more specific about what *"extra characters"* means and provide sample of bookmarklet.js. See [mcve]

Comment: charlietfl, I can't add JSfiddle to my post because of SO rules apparently. If they're not watching th comment though, here it is:  https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=xm9pbIKB5C

Comment: doesn't explain extra characters and no reason you can't add a link in question either. Would remove all comments and minify that code though

Comment: I just updated it with the resulting bookmarklet in the HTML section. So bottom part is bookmarklet JS that works and top is the resulting bookmarklet.

Comment: Minifying the code just breaks my HTML when I try to include it.